# How can I "pivot" materialized view dependency results from Redshift's system view "STV_MV_DEPS"?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

I am working in Redshift, and I want to create a result set that lists the materialized view dependency order from the bottom most child to the top parent so that I can later refresh these views manually in order. The procedure would have a schema name and view name passed as a parameter.

Currently, by using the built in view STV_MV_DEPS, I can get the parent and child view info like below:

| MView name | Referenced MView name |
| --- | --- |
| MView 3 | MView 2 |
| MView 2 | MView 1 |

AKA mview 3 references mview 2 which references mview 1 which does not reference a mview (known because there is not a record for mview 1 in this result).

I want this procedure to return a result set that lists the view dependencies from child to parent like so:

| Index | MView name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MView 1 |
| 2 | MView 2 |
| 3 | MView 3 |

This way I can use this order to run my refreshes from 1 to 3:

`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW MView1; REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW MView2; REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW MView3;`

**Note**: Auto-refresh is not a possibility here. If you think you have a solution that requires a different approach than what I am proposing then let me know. However, I want this to be within the lines of Redshift if possible.

I've tried thinking of solutions using loops and unions, but haven't thought of anything that would work.